# How to increase yytext size in lex

Tags: lex

The maximum number of characters that are being parsed is 1024. I am using flex. I need to be able to parse large strings into the buffer. I am trying to use

```
setupbuf(size)
int size;
{
  yy_current_buffer = yy_create_buffer(yyin, size);
}
```

but this is complaining of syntax. Please given your inputs.

Comment: This link might help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.misc/mVCQUSJEg-w

Answer (score 1):

You can write your string to file and then can use yy_create_buffer(FILE*,Size) or can use the yyin mechanism to read files.